# Is It Valid To Calculate Model-Averaged Confidence Intervals In the Same Way As Model Averaged Predictions?

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, model-averaging, glmmtmb

I'm fitting a series of mixed-effects models, and I'm trying to calculate the model-averaged predictions and their confidence intervals. If I have a set of $R$ models $\{M_1,...,M_R\}$ I know that when calculating model-averaged predictions, the model-averaged estimator $\hat{\theta}$ of $\theta$ is calculated via:
$$\hat{\theta} = \sum_{i=1}^R w_i\hat{\theta_i},$$

where $\hat{\theta_i}$ is the predicted value of $\theta$ under model $M_i$ and $w_i$ is the weight of $M_i$. **My question is regarding the confidence intervals.** If I can get a confidence interval specifying a lower bound $x_i$ and and upper bound $y_i$ for each model $M_i$, can I then calculate the model-averaged lower bound $\hat{x_i}$ (and subsequently the upper bound) as
$$\hat{x_i} = \sum_{i=1}^R w_i\hat{x_i}.$$

The model type I'm working with (`glmmTMB`) doesn't support the `re.form` argument in `predict()` yet so I am having a hard time using existing methods (`MuMIn`) to calculate the model-averaged confidence intervals.

So I'm curious if this is, while not ideal, a valid way to estimate the confidence intervals of the predictions.

Comment: See our discussion about the reliability of various methods to calculate CIs here https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ecm.1309 About glmmTMB - 1.0 does has limited support for re.form. Why do you need this anyway, is this a MuMIn requirement? I assume you would always average with conditional predictions, so the default of glmmTMB should be fine.